# How to do FLASK SQLALCHEMY query for Association Table

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two models in **MANY TO MANY** Relationship and I want to get all the column values in related models in one query. But cannot get that using Flask SQLAlchemy.

But I able to get the required data using the SQL query in phpmyadmin.

Here is the query

> SELECT ply_positions.plyPositionId, ply_positions.plyPositionName,
>   ply_positions.createdAt, ply_positions.updatedAt,
>   product_categories.productCatName FROM ply_positions JOIN
>   product_category_ply_position AS product_category_ply_position_1 ON
>   ply_positions.plyPositionId =
>   product_category_ply_position_1.plyPositionId JOIN product_categories
>   ON product_categories.productCatId =
>   product_category_ply_position_1.productCatId

Here are the code for **models** and **Resources** on Gist :- https://gist.github.com/himadriganguly/c0c9d7e247c286e497998dbd33ce7e84

OUTPUT:

> [
>       {
>           "product_category": [
>               1
>           ],
>           "plyPositionId": 2,
>           "updatedAt": null,
>           "product_category_associations": [
>               {
>                   "productCatId": 1,
>                   "plyPositionId": 2
>               }
>           ],
>           "createdAt": 1234,
>           "plyPositionName": "Flute"
>       },
>       {
>           "product_category": [
>               1
>           ],
>           "plyPositionId": 1,
>           "updatedAt": null,
>           "product_category_associations": [
>               {
>                   "productCatId": 1,
>                   "plyPositionId": 1
>               }
>           ],
>           "createdAt": 123,
>           "plyPositionName": "Top"
>       } ]

Getting the output of the association table but not the column values of from product_categories table.

Also while creating a relationship we use lazy two times but why we are doing this is not clear to me.

> ply_position = db.relationship('PlyPositionModel',
>           secondary="product_category_ply_position", lazy=True,
>           backref=db.backref('product_category', lazy=True))

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out it is not the issue of SqlAlchemy it is about how you serialize the data. In this case, I am using flask-marshmallow.

So in plyPositionResource.py I have to change the schema a bit

**ProductCategorySchema**

```
class ProductCategorySchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        model = ProductCategoryModel
```

**PlyPositionSchema**

```
class PlyPositionSchema(ma.ModelSchema):
    productcategories = fields.List(fields.Nested(ProductCategorySchema))
    class Meta:
        model = PlyPositionModel
```

And after that in get function you can do the following

```
def get(self):
        plyPositionResource = PlyPositionModel.query.order_by(\
            PlyPositionModel.plyPositionId.desc())\
            .all()

        plyPositions = plypositions_schema.dump(plyPositionResource).data

        return({"data": plyPositions}, 200)
```

Hope this will help others.

If there is another way to solve the problem please feel free to comment.